# Is there any way to set filename pattern for FTP inbound request in Mule

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

I have a ftp folder where files are written periodically with different extensions.I need to read only those files having extensions lets say '*.run' .Is there a way to set file name pattern in ftp inbound connector.

I have tried wild filename-wildcard-filter buts that is not working.

Comment: Can you share your config that is not working and your Mule version?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my sample flow looking for .txt files and its working as expected.

```
 <flow name="ftpcleintFlow">
    <sftp:inbound-endpoint host="${sftp.host}" port="22" path="//" user="admin" password="admin" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="SFTP" archiveDir="C:\files" pollingFrequency="60000" autoDelete="true">
      <file:filename-wildcard-filter pattern="*.txt"></file:filename-wildcard-filter>
    </sftp:inbound-endpoint>
    <logger message="#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```